# Inline all static imports in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

I was cleaning up some code and happened upon `com.example.StringHelper` that contained 6 or 7 `public static` methods (for example `concatStrings(String...)`, but no member fields. There were a number of classes subclassing this class just so they could call `concatStrings(str1, str2)` without prefixing it with the class like so: `StringHelper.concatStrings(str1, str2)`.

I didn't want them subclassing a class just for that reason, so I broke a bunch off. I pasted the following static import into the top of any file subclassing it after removing the `extends StringHelper`:

```
import static com.example.StringHelper.*;
```

Eclipse simplified this into specific imports for only the methods being used.

**Question**: Is there a simple way to have Eclipse "inline" these static imports? Can I get it to remove the actual static import and prefix every call with `StringHelper.` instead?

**Note**
This is a simplified contrived example, so please don't complain about why we need a StringHelper in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do it:

- Highlight one invocation of concatStrings(). Make sure to include the parentheses in the highlighting. Select Refactor/Extract Method, call it foo. Make sure to check the "Replace 47 additional occurrences of statements with method"
- In your new foo method, add the "StringHelper." prefix to the invocation of concatStrings
- remove the import static
- Do Refactor/Inline to get rid of foo and put your static calls back where they belong, along with their shiny new Prefixes.

Comment: When I select concatStrings and choose "Extract Method...", I get a popup saying "Cannot extract a single method name."

Comment: You need to select the parentheses also, not just the method name.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if there's an automatic way, but I *think* it can help in a manual way. Delete the import, then click on each line with an error on it. Press ctrl-1 for 'quick fix' and choose the quick fix that prefixes the package name rather than add an import.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think the quick fix knows about the class it's from if I delete the static import. Regardless, a find-replace on each method would probably be faster (some classes use a method 20 times throughout).

Answer (score 0):

```
Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Organize Imports
```

There you can configure how many imports will be required to group them.

Comment: I'm not complaining about it breaking the StringHelper.* static import line into one for each of the 3 methods used. I'm asking if I can get eclipse to remove the static import lines completely and prefix the method call with StringHelper instead.

Answer (score 0):

Preferences > Java > Code Style > Organize Imports:

"Number of static imports needed for .*" set this to 1.